# How Can You Open Android Application Property Pages in MAUI

Tags: maui

I have a MAUI app that uses Contacts; this feature was added after the initial release.  People that upgrade the app didn't grant permissions to Contacts when the app was first installed because we weren't asking for it then (since we weren't using it).  I can capture the fact that they're getting denied access, but is there a way in MAUI that I can navigate through the Android settings (like I've seen other apps do) to open the Permissions page for our app so users can more easily grant us permissions to Contacts?

Comment: Googling, I see multiple questions on this topic. Those discussions are not related to Maui - you'd do this in Android-specific code, so any Android answer should get you started.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It took a bit of bumbling around, but I found a solution that will open the app's settings page, and you can click on Permissions from there. I got mixed result in researching this, but it sounded like you can't open the Permissions page directly.  In any case, here is the code in case it is helpful to you:

#if ANDROID

```
    //from:  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java
    string APP_DETAIL_SETTINGS = "android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS";

    var act = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity;

    Android.Net.Uri appUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + act.PackageName);

    Android.Content.Intent tent = new Android.Content.Intent(APP_DETAIL_SETTINGS, appUri);

    tent.AddCategory(Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault);

    tent.SetFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.NewTask);

    act.StartActivity(tent);
```

#endif

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much more simply than what is depicted in your self accepted best answer, and do it across all platforms by simply calling:

```
AppInfo.Current.ShowSettingsUI();
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understand correctly.

> is there a way in MAUI that I can navigate through the Android
> settings (like I've seen other apps do) to open the Permissions page
> for our app so users can more easily grant us permissions to Contacts?

First, add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Then open Setting->Apps&notifications-> Select App ->Permissions->Contacts

For more information, you can [check Contacts - .NET MAUI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/contacts?tabs=android&view=net-maui-7.0) and [Permissions - .NET MAUI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios).

Comment: Thanks, what you are describing is doing it manually.  I'm asking how to programmatically open to that Android settings page.